# Is there any *testability-explorer* like tool for Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

[testability-explorer](http://code.google.com/p/testability-explorer/) is a tool for measuring how hard to unit test java program. Is there any tool like this for Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Python is a dynamic language, "examining" the bytecode may reveal approximately nothing useful.  A Python program can use `exec`, `execfile()` and `__import__()` to introduce code "on-the-fly", defeating bytecode analysis.

Non-Mockable Total Recursive Cyclomatic Complexity.  Assuming the bytecode is actually all of the code being executed, the Total Recursive Cyclomatic Complexity can be computed.  The idea of non-mockable, however, doesn't apply to Python.  Python has monkey-patching, making it very easy to mock almost anything in Python.

Assuming that there are `exec`, `execfile()` and `__import__()` operations involved means that the only way to compute the actual total cyclomatic complexity is a combination of analysis plus execution.

Global Mutable State.  There are module globals plus proper `global` globals.  The module globals are "free variables" and can be found by examination of the bytecode.  The `global` globals are all specifically labeled with `global` and can be found in the source just as easily as the byte code.

Law of Demeter. This **is** interesting and could be found through an examination of the bytecode.  However, the caveats above apply.  It would only be useful assuming that there are no `exec`, `execfile()` or `__import__()` operations.

Since most of the analysis in the testability explorer can't easily be applied to Python, it's not surprising that folks don't spend a lot of time trying to write a tool like that.

Comment: @Marco Mariani: Like all dynamic languages (Lisp, Ruby, Scheme, etc.) it resists trivial static analysis.